# npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree. Clone repository

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
MINGW64 ~/Downloads/Eshop_mobile_app_react_native (master)
$ npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: Eshop@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.2" from the root project    
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   react-dom@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-04T22_30_23_958Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried running  `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` and tried running `$ npx react-native run-android` but the build is failing, and I don't know what to do anymore.

```
MINGW64 ~/Downloads/Eshop_mobile_app_react_native (master)
$ npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1735 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...



> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileJava

> Configure project :app
Unable to detect AGP versions for included builds. All projects in the build should use the same AGP version. Class name for the included build object: org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuild$IncludedBuildImpl_Decorated.

> Configure project :lottie-react-native

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
AAR for react-native-reanimated has been found
C:\Users\PC\Downloads\Eshop_mobile_app_react_native\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\react-native-reanimated-68-jsc.aar



Note: C:\Users\PC\Downloads\Eshop_mobile_app_react_native\android\app\src\debug\java\com\eshop\ecommerce\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.



* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 48s

    at makeError (C:\Users\PC\Downloads\Eshop_mobile_app_react_native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\PC\Downloads\Eshop_mobile_app_react_native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\PC\Downloads\Eshop_mobile_app_react_native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\PC\Downloads\Eshop_mobile_app_react_native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Comment: I see a few warnings, but can't see errors, try `npx react-native run-android --verbose` maybe it'll show what those 2 actual errors are. The npm install thing is probably fine and your workaround should work.